# Перегрузка двойной индексации C++

Tags: перегрузка-операторов, c++

Пусть имеется класс Matrix:

```
    class matrix
    { 
       public:

          int row;
          int col;
          double **M;

          matrix (int i, int j) {
              row = i;  
              col = j;
              M = new double*[row];

              for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                  M[i] = new double[col];
                  for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                      M[i][j] = 0;
                  }
              }
         };
     };
```

Нужно реализовать перегрузку двойной индексации на чтение и на запись элемента матрицы. Ход моих мыслей:

1. Сделаю сначала на чтение, это легко =>

   ```
   double* operator [] (int i, int j){ return M[i][j]; }
   ```
2. Угу... много параметров... =>

   ```
   friend double* operator [] (int i, int j){ return M[i][j]; }
   ```
3. `operator[] must be a member function` ...хм...блин...

Вопрос: В чем проблема? Как исправить? =)

Comment: Всегда принимает ОДИН параметр:

    T* operator [](T assoc){...}

Так как этот оператор не может быть перегружен извне, поэтому всегда и только всегда!

Comment: Посмотрите ещё вот этот вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/178553/

Comment: C C++23 можно использовать `operator[]` с несколькими параметрами.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так не получится. Индексация в С++ всегда одинарная. Запись M[x][y] означает (M[x])[y]
Просто M[x] должен возвращать строку, а далее к строке применяется её индексация.

```
double* operator [] (int i){return M[i];}
```

Comment: Ага, понял, спасибо! А на запись, я так понял достаточно написать подобное (M[x])[y]=value;?

Comment: Да круглые скобки не нужны, это я для ясности. Пишем просто

    M[x][y]=value;

А вот M[x] присваивать нельзя, будет ошибка что-то типа "требуется l-значение"

Comment: ну оно и ясно, массив ведь двумерный, а значит требуется второй индекс для записи значения. Но все равно я что то не понимаю, если в теле перегрузки идет обыкновенный возврат указателя на значение, то каким образом он записывает значение?

Comment: Первая (перегруженная) индексация возвращает указатель,

   double *N = M[x];

далее указатель мы можем использовать как массив, другими словами у него определена своя операция индексации, которая возвращает double&. Можем писать:

   N[y]=value;

Теперь то же самое, но в одну строчку:

   M[x][y]=value;

Comment: Вот спасибо, хорошо) Благодарю за ответ, Все понял!)

Comment: Кстати можно было сделать хитрее, возвращать не double*, а ссылку на дополнительный класс "вектор", для которого перегрузить индексацию так, чтобы возвращалось double&.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MMassiveInt
{
private:
    class submasint;// подкласс строк матрицы (объявление)
    int row, col; // количества строк и колонок матрицы
    submasint *arrint; // указатель на массив подкласса строк матрицы
    class submasint// подкласс строк матрицы (реализация)
    {
    public:
        int *sarrint;
        // конструктор по умолчанию необходим для создания массива указателей на класс подстрок матрицы
        submasint() {}
        submasint(int size)
        {
            sarrint = new int[size]; // создание массива целочисленных данных
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//инициализация полей нулями
            {
                sarrint[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        int & operator [] (int i) // оператор [] возвращает ссылку на int
        {
            return sarrint[i];
        }
        // деструктор не нужен, если если его поставить, то строки матрицы будут 
        // удаляться до того, как заполнится вся матрица
        //      ~submasint()   
        //{
        //  if (sarrint != nullptr) delete[] sarrint;
        //}
    };

public:
    MMassiveInt(const int rows, const int cols) //класс матрица целых чисел
    {
        rows < 1 ? row = 1: row = rows; // защита от ввода количества строк или столбцов менее 1
        cols < 1 ? col = 1: col = cols;
        // создание массива указателей с использованием конструктора по умолчанию (без параметров)
        arrint = new submasint [row]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            // создания строк матрицы. если у подкласса строк матрицы будет деструктор,
            // то строки будут удаляться в каждей итерации цикла
            arrint[i] = submasint(col);
        }
    }
    submasint & operator [] (int i)// оператор [] возвращает ссылку на подкласс строк матрицы
    {
        return arrint[i];
    }
    int GetCol() // метод получения количества колонок матрицы
    {
        return col;
    }
    int GetRow()// метод получения количества строк матрицы
    {
        return row;
    }
    ~MMassiveInt()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {// удаление строк матрицы
            if (arrint[i].sarrint!=nullptr)
            delete[]  (arrint[i].sarrint);
        }
        if (arrint!=nullptr)
        delete[] arrint;// удаление массива указателей на строки матрицы
    }
};
int main()
{
    int mrow = 2, mcol = 3; // инициализация значения количество строк и столбцов матрицы
    MMassiveInt mas(mrow, mcol); // создание двумерного массива, и инициализация его полей нулями
    // вывода матрицы в консоль 
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetRow(); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < mas.GetCol(); k++)
            {
                cout << mas[i][k] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Аналогично делается и для Double.