# Перегрузка оператора [][]

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Перегрузить оператор `[]` несложно.

Но что делать, если мне нужен двумерный массив?

Как перегрузить оператор `[][]`?

Если я пишу `[]` с двумя параметрами - ругается. 
Если пишу `[][]` - ругается:

> ```
> error C2092: тип элемента массива "[]" не может быть функцией
> ```

вот как я объявляю:

```
double& operator [][] (const int i, const int j);
```

Comment: Вся эта многомерная дискуссия только укрепляет меня в мысли о том, что перегрузка оператора это **зло**!

Comment: @Barmaley это надо понимать как "перегрузка операторов в С++ -- зло"?

Comment: @alexlz Перегрузка операторов как инструмент программиста это зло. Язык тут не причем. В Java тоже есть нечто похожее на перегрузку операторов - например сложение строк или присвоение к примитивным типам (автобоксинг), но это так сказать фичи языка, а не инструмент программиста.

Comment: @Barmaley "инструмент программиста", "фичи языка"... Попроще нельзя, на пальцах? Ну скажем на примере классов типов в haskell.

Comment: Про оценку "перегрузки операторов" полностьюю согласен с @Barmaley. 


А во многих случаях к одинаковым именам методов это тоже относится.

Comment: @avp не надо мне говорить "норд-норд-ост", Вы мне пальцем покажите.

Comment: К вопросу зло-не зло: дополню фразу megа
"правильно изменить эту имплементацию вы сможете только тогда, когда поймете ее зависимости. А поймете Вы ее только в том виде, в котором она Вам привычнее. Если для Вас понятнее реализации с () - это ваш путь, нет - увы."

Ещё иногда нужно найти, допустим, все вызовы перегруженного оператора. По имени можно найти, а по () []? :) Хотя если повезло, можно закомментировать метод и компилятор сам скажет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перегрузка двойной индексации C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/121024/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-c)

Comment: C C++23 можно использовать `operator[]` с несколькими параметрами.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Вы не первый, кого интересует эта проблема; этот вопрос даже попал в своё время в официальный список часто задаваемых вопросов по С++.

Знаменитый [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op) советует использовать `operator ()`:

> Используйте `operator()`, а не `operator[]`.
>
> Если у вас многомерный массив, наиболее чистое решение -- использовать `operator()`,  а не `operator[]`. Причина в том, что `operator[]` всегда принимает один параметр, в то время как `operator()` принимает любое их количество (в случае прямоугольной матрицы, вам нужно два).

[Вот здесь](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-array-of-array) и [здесь](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-c-style-subscript) объяснение, почему круглые скобки лучше двух пар квадратных.

Краткое резюме:

1. квадратные скобки требуют создания промежуточного объекта, представляющего строку таблицы, что накладывает ограничение на физическое расположение данных в основном классе.
2. круглые скобки очевидно ни при каких условиях не хуже, а иногда лучше
3. использование нативного для С++ синтаксиса лучше
4. проверка входных параметров проще, что улучшает качество кода

Comment: Это, скорее вопрос привычки и лояльности. Кому-то [][] позволяет переключить свое внимание с реализации матрицы на решение задачи, а кому-то - удобнее использовать `Matrix( 5, 7 )` вместо `Matrix[5][7]`. Конечно, использование промежуточного объекта дороже, но на практике обычно дороже именно то самое **переключение внимания на саму задачу**.

Comment: @mega: мне кажется, налагаемые ограничения на физический лэйаут гораздо более страшны. представьте, например, что вы захотели изменить имплементацию на разреженную матрицу. (и моё мнение подкрепляется мнением товарища Marshall Cline)

Comment: >представьте, например, что вы захотели изменить имплементацию на разреженную матрицу

Очень легко могу представить, не раз сталкивался с запутанными реализациями многомерности. И вот тут как раз могу ручаться - изменить эту имплементацию вы сможете только тогда, когда поймете ее зависимости. А поймете Вы ее только в том виде, в котором она Вам привычнее. Если для Вас понятнее реализации с `()` - это ваш путь, нет - увы.

Comment: @mega: а теперь прикиньте, если вы перейдёте к разреженной матрице внутри, как реализовывать объект "строка", который будет возвращать оператор []? накладывать условие, чтобы матрица непременно хранилась по строкам? держать в памяти объекты для пустых строк тоже? или обновлять их, если кто-то добавит ненулевой элемент в матрицу? круглые скобки уберут весь геморрой.

Comment: >накладывать условие, чтобы матрица непременно хранилась по строкам?

На сколько я знаю, универсального-то решения тут нет. Все зависит от характера разреженности. Если **выгоднее** реализовать неразделяемый доступ к ячейкам - это одно. Но если **понятнее** будет оставить сегментированным - это другой вопрос. А компромис - это проектировщик, который примет правильное решение.  
 --  
Только вот правильное и понятное - это разные вещи. **Не каждому правильному решению может быть найден правильный решатель.** Если от этого зависит успех проекта, лучше пусть решение будет понятным.

Comment: @mega: я немного о другом. допустим, вы делаете индексацию квадратными скобками. тогда вам _с необходимостью_ нужен объект "строка". либо вы отдельно копируете в него данные (что жутко неэффективно!), либо у вас внутри матрицы данные для строк должны присутствовать, и объект "строка" будет на них ссылаться. второй случай означает, что вы обязаны использовать именно построчный layout данных, вне зависимости от того, как на самом деле правильно для вашей задачи.

Comment: Не очень понял Вашу мысль, @VladD. В общем случае, последовательный доступ к данным эффективнее случайного, сколь-бы ни давало выигрыш по объему разреженное размещение объектов. Поэтому в решениях, которые 90% ищут по иерархии и 10% работают с данными, объекты не размещают в узлах иерархии. Просто минимизируют размеры самой иерархии, чтобы на нее попадало минимальное число страниц памяти.

Comment: На самом деле странно, что никто не упомянул еще один способ. А именно - создание объекта вроде `TIndex (1,2)`, принимающего нужное кол-во целых чисел. Да хоть вещественных на самом деле. Но вот работа с массивом становится существенно менее красивой.

Comment: @gecube: Да, этот способ особенно полезен, когда может быть большое или вообще переменное количество индексов. Вообще, разделение концепций (подготовка индекса/ов от его применения) -- хорошо.

Answer (score 8):

> как перегрузить оператор `[][]`?

Аналогично, как и с оператором `++` - это решается вводом промежуточного итератора, который возвращается из оператора `[]`.

Пример итератора повторять не буду, он есть, например тут: ["operator++ для node в List'е"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/163541#163604). Только вместо `++` следует перегрузить `[]`.

А, впрочем, вот:

```
template< typename Type >
class Matrix{

  Type*pData;
  int cx, cy;

  class Iterator{
    Type*pRow;
    Type operator[]( int i ){ return pRow[i]; }
    Iterator( Type*pRow ) : pRow( pRow ){}
    ...
  };

  Iterator operator[]( int i ){ return pData + i * cx; }
  Matrix( int cx, int cy ) : cx( cx ), cy( cy ){
    pData = new Type[cx*cy];
  }
  ...
};
```

Вышло даже короче :)

Comment: Не понял с оператором ++ (а также --) - его  можно перегружать без дополнительных телодвижений, как для префиксного, так и постфиксного варианта.

Comment: >Не понял с оператором ++ (а также --) - его можно перегружать без дополнительных телодвижений, как для префиксного, так и постфиксного варианта.

Его можно перегрузить только на классе, как и с оператором `[][]`. Ввод класса - это и есть дополнительное телодвижение и там и тут.

Comment: >Его можно перегрузить только на классе

Не понял

Comment: >Не понял

Да ладно? Что именно Вы не поняли? Вы можете перегрузить оператор `[]` за пределами какого-либо класса? Ну перегрузите `[]` для `int*` :)

Comment: А причем тут int?

Comment: >А причем тут int?

Не `int`, а `int*`. А при том, что `int*` - классом не является, соответственно оператор `[]` для него перегрузить не получится. А теперь скажите, что Вам не понятно было изначально?

Comment: @mega, речь о том, что раз речь идет про пользовательский класс, то можно операторы ++ и [] перегрузить на нем, а не вводить вспомогательный класс. А оператора [][] вообще нет. Вот поэтому мне ответ @VladD нравится больше.

Comment: @gecube, очевидно, про существование оператора `[][]` я не писал ни слова. Ни чего не говорил и про невозможность перегрузки операторов `++` и `[]` в "пользовательском классе". Этот минус я Вам возвращаю, ибо не к месту претензии. Речь изначально шла о перегрузке операторов **на указателе**, в связи с чем и ссылка в ответе на аналогичный вопрос, в связи с чем и пример для @mikillskegg с перегрузкой `int*`. А ответ @VlaD'а мне тоже понравился, жаль, он не на этот вопрос. :)

Answer (score 4):

Делается дополнительный класс с перегруженным оператором []. А в основном классе оператор [] возвращает экземпляр дополнительного класса. А просто так перегрузить [][] не получиться - нет такого оператора.

Comment: И зачем нужно было повторять ответ?

Comment: Когда я писал,  Вашего небыло. И в моем ответе ничего нет об итераторах.

Comment: Сортировка на форуме работает так, что ответы с одинаковыми голосами идут в порядке их создания. Мой ответ висел минут 5-7 первым, пока @mikillskegg не растерялся в непонятных вопросах, темы мягко говоря не касающихся. Неприятно.

Comment: Смутно понимаю, что Вы написали. Когда я начал писать - было ноль ответов. Когда я нажал "ответить" и этим отправил свой ответ, и страница обновилась - увидел Ваш ответ и возле него было написано "отвечено 15 секунд назад". Так как я писал с телефона, то писал медленно.
Ещё раз пишу - когда я писал свой ответ -не было других. Так что я не дублировал.

Comment: >Смутно понимаю, что Вы написали. Когда я начал писать - было ноль ответов. Когда я нажал "ответить" и страница обновилась -увидел Ваш ответ и возле него было написано "отвечено 15 секунд назад". Так как я писал с телефона, то писал медленно.

Вот поэтому я и спрашивал, зачем было повторять ответ, раз уж Вы сразу увидели, что вопрос так уже отвечен.

Comment: @mega, затем, что @KoVadim увидел ваш ответ уже по факту отправки своего. На тот момент, когда он начал писать свой ответ, вашего еще не было. Что именно Вы не поняли?

Comment: >затем, что @KoVadim увидел ваш ответ уже по факту отправки своего. На тот момент, когда он начал писать свой ответ, вашего еще не было. Что именно Вы не поняли?

Я не понял, зачем было оставлять повтор ответа. Отсутствие слова "итератор" ни как на решение не влияет. В аналогичной ситуации, я бы удалил свой ответ, если бы в нем не было примеров. Но даже если бы был - скорректировал бы его в качестве дополнения к уже отвеченному.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то я не понял про дополнительный класс. У меня давным-давно имеется класс TMatrix, которым я изо всех сил пользуюсь.

```
class TMatrix
{
  private:
    int line, col;
    double **m;
  public:
    TMatrix(const int l, const int c);
    ~TMatrix();
   ...................................................
   double* operator [](const int i)const {return m[i];}
};
```

Там еще много всего, но перегруженный [] я показал, а скобки второго индекса в перегрузке не нуждаются. 
Сейчас мне достанется от [@avp](/users/232/avp).

Comment: А где здесь перегруженный `[][]`? Перегруженный `[]` - вижу, а вот `[][]` - увы, нет. Второй `[]` не перегружен. Как был, так и остался.

Comment: @mega, он здесь не нужен в перегруженном виде. Достаточно перегрузить первые скобки.

TMatrix ma = TMatrix(3,4); ma[1][2] = 5.4;

Comment: ... и потерять проверку выхода индекса за границы диапазона?

Comment: Можно подумать, что на линейном массиве, применяя нативный [], мы эту проверку обретаем.

Comment: именно поэтому считается, что С-style-массивы в С++ -- [зло](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html).

Comment: >Можно подумать, что на линейном массиве, применяя нативный [], мы эту проверку обретаем.

Вот Вы как раз и применяете нативный []

Comment: Да, пожалуйста, можно делать Матрицу из векторов. Но я вот уже 30 лет живу с этим "злом" и надеюсь дожить, так ни разу и не ошибившись и применяя этот класс, практически, во всех своих задачах.

Comment: @BuilderC: это значит, что вы 30 лет пишете на чистом С и не пользуетесь преимуществами С++. Воля ваша, конечно, но зачем же советовать другим?

Comment: вы 30 лет пишете на чистом С

Я еще и машинные кода застал.

Comment: @BuilderC: попробуйте С++, он классный! :-P

Comment: >Но я вот уже 30 лет живу с этим "злом"

Ну, вообще-то за последние 30 лет С++ несколько изменился...

Comment: @BuilderC

      class TMatrix

Борланд всегда живой, Борланд всегда с тобой... 

      Я еще и машинные кода застал.

Если не секрет, то какие (какой контупер)?

@VladD

      попробуйте С++, он классный! :-P

В 90е годы по мотивам рекламы был анекдот: "А Вы УПСА не пробовали?..."

Comment: "Что-то я не понял про дополнительный класс." дополнительный класс позволяет осуществлять дополнительный контроль доступа к объекту (и всякое такое). Если этого не требуется, то можно и указатель возвращать.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно [][] перегрузить не удастся. Чтобы достичь эффекта, надо создать собственный контейнер или воспользоваться стандартным с перегруженным [] который возвращает либо ссылку на контейнер с другим перегруженным [] либо указатель на целевой тип данных. И тогда будет счастье.

Answer (score 1):

Разберешься.

```
#include <iostream>
class matrix
{
public:
    int m,n;
    int** pMatrix;

    int* operator[](int elem)
    { 
        return pMatrix[elem];
    }
    void coutput()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                printf("%-5d",pMatrix[i][j]);
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }   
} a;

int main()
{
    a.m = 10;
    a.n = 10;
    a.pMatrix = new int*[a.m];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.m; i++)
        a.pMatrix[i] = new int[a.n];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a.n; j++)
            a.pMatrix[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);
    a.coutput();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, из того, что разобрал - такой ответ уже есть у @BuilderC

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MMassiveInt
{
private:
    class submasint;// подкласс строк матрицы (объявление)
    int row, col; // количества строк и колонок матрицы
    submasint *arrint; // указатель на массив подкласса строк матрицы
    class submasint// подкласс строк матрицы (реализация)
    {
    public:
        int *sarrint;
        // конструктор по умолчанию необходим для создания массива указателей на класс подстрок матрицы
        submasint() {}
        submasint(int size)
        {
            sarrint = new int[size]; // создание массива целочисленных данных
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//инициализация полей нулями
            {
                sarrint[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        int & operator [] (int i) // оператор [] возвращает ссылку на int
        {
            return sarrint[i];
        }
        // деструктор не нужен, если если его поставить, то строки матрицы будут 
        // удаляться до того, как заполнится вся матрица
        //      ~submasint()   
        //{
        //  if (sarrint != nullptr) delete[] sarrint;
        //}
    };

public:
    MMassiveInt(const int rows, const int cols) //класс матрица целых чисел
    {
        rows < 1 ? row = 1: row = rows; // защита от ввода количества строк или столбцов менее 1
        cols < 1 ? col = 1: col = cols;
        // создание массива указателей с использованием конструктора по умолчанию (без параметров)
        arrint = new submasint [row]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            // создания строк матрицы. если у подкласса строк матрицы будет деструктор,
            // то строки будут удаляться в каждей итерации цикла
            arrint[i] = submasint(col);
        }
    }
    submasint & operator [] (int i)// оператор [] возвращает ссылку на подкласс строк матрицы
    {
        return arrint[i];
    }
    int GetCol() // метод получения количества колонок матрицы
    {
        return col;
    }
    int GetRow()// метод получения количества строк матрицы
    {
        return row;
    }
    ~MMassiveInt()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {// удаление строк матрицы
            if (arrint[i].sarrint!=nullptr)
            delete[]  (arrint[i].sarrint);
        }
        if (arrint!=nullptr)
        delete[] arrint;// удаление массива указателей на строки матрицы
    }
};
int main()
{
    int mrow = 2, mcol = 3; // инициализация значения количество строк и столбцов матрицы
    MMassiveInt mas(mrow, mcol); // создание двумерного массива, и инициализация его полей нулями
    // вывода матрицы в консоль 
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetRow(); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < mas.GetCol(); k++)
            {
                cout << mas[i][k] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

вот полный перегруз, чтобы можно было не к полю обращаться, а к самому объекту

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы вернуть N-мерный массив `arr[a0][a1][a2]..[aN]`, достаточно перегрузить оператор [] так, что бы он возвращал указатель- `return(&arr[a0][0][0]..[0]);`

Остальное сделает компилятор. Ему нужно знать лишь расположение *первого индекса*.

Comment: Даже если так сделать, это будет указатель на n-мерный массив, а не n-мерный массив.